# Put for if in one line python

Tags: python, list

Say i have one list:

```
v=['one','','two','three','',]
```

Now i want to filter out all the empty values:

```
for i in v:
  if i==''
    pass
  else:
    print(i)
```

I want to do this in one line :

```
vr=[i if i!='' else pass for i in v]
```

getting bellow error.

```
 File "<console>", line 1
 vr=[i if i!='' else pass for i in vt1]
                     ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Kindly suggest .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following

```
>>> v=['one','','two','three','',]
>>> vr = [i for i in v if i]
>>> vr
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Comment: Its working . Thanks man . Can you please suggest me some modern python tutorial for this kind of stuff .

Comment: I would like to have some suggestion for python class concept . What u would suggest

Answer (score 2):

```
v=['one','','two','three','',]
print(*[i for i in v if i], sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

`vr=[i for i in v if i!='']` boom

Answer (score 1):

If your interested on different approach

Python 3.x:

```
vr = list(filter(('').__ne__, v))
```

Python 2.x:

```
vr = filter(lambda a: a != '', v)
```

Comment: It is considered bad form to use "dunder" methods directly. For nice looking `map` and `filter`, use the `operator` module, maybe in conjunction with `partial`, so this becomes `from operator import ne; from functools import partial` then just `filter(partial(ne, ''), v)`. However, in this case, because `''` is falsy, you could simply use `filter(None, v)`

Comment: Dully noted @juanpa.arrivillaga